# Spring MVC input validation

Tags: java, spring, validation, spring-mvc

Is there a way to check that every variable entering a requestmapped method in Spring MVC controller has been validated by at least 1 Bean Validation annotation ?

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more with some examples